# CursorAdapter and Button

Tags: android, button, android-cursoradapter

I have a database. The values from the database are displayed in a listview. The listview has a Bitmap, 4 TextViews and 2 Buttons. 
I wrote two different OnClickListeners for my 2 Buttons, but both methods are not succesful. When I click on the buttons the program chrashes, when it tries to do "tvText1.setText(...)"

Has anybody an idea how to fix it?

**The buttons in the xml-file does look like:**

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonON" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="btnButtonONclicked"
        android:text="ON" />

<Button android:id="@+id/buttonOFF" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="OFF" />
```

**This is my CursorAdapter**

```
public class ModuleCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    public ModuleCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cur) {
        super(context, R.layout.notes_row, cur);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cur, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return li.inflate(R.layout.notes_row, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {        
        TextView tvText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        TextView tvText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        TextView tvText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
        TextView tvText4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text4);
        ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        Button btnButtonON = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonON);
        Button btnButtonOFF = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOFF);

        tvText1.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
        tvText2.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICETYPE)));
        tvText3.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_HOMECODE)));
        tvText4.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICECODE)));

        String filename = "modul_r_" + cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICETYPE));
        int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(filename, "drawable", "com.module.main");     
        ivIcon.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id));            

        btnButtonON.setTag(id);

        btnButtonOFF.setTag(id);
        btnButtonOFF.setOnClickListener(btnButtonOFFclicked);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }       

     public void btnButtonONclicked(View view) {
         TextView tvText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            tvText1.setText("On");
     }


    private OnClickListener btnButtonOFFclicked = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView tvText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            tvText1.setText("Off");
        }
    };
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Cheers

Felix

**Comment.**

*The whole Layout-file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/my_icon"/>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView android:text="Code: " 
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text3" 
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/buttonON" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:onClick="btnButtonONclicked"
        android:text="ON" />

<Button android:id="@+id/buttonOFF" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="OFF" />
```

**Comment Comment:**

Now I deleted the tv.Text1.setText("On"). For the On-button there is still a exeption. For the Off-button is the system.out.println() working well.

This is the part of the code:

```
         public void btnButtonONclicked(View view) {
         //  Still an exeption thrown
     }


    private OnClickListener btnButtonOFFclicked = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("Hello. Here is the message.");
            //  working fine
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: What is the log exception your getting?

Comment: Debug gives me: Thread[<1> main] (Suspend (exeption NullPointerException)). When I rund adb logcat in the shell than I only get "D/dalvikvm(  124): GC_EXPLICIT freed 149 objects / 7776 bytes in 60ms".

Comment: Debug gives me for the first button: Thread[<1> main] (Suspend (exeption IllegalStateExeption. Debug gives me for the second button: Thread[<1> main] (Suspend (exeption NullPointerException)).

Comment: Hello. I added a new information. See  "Comment comment" above.

Comment: Just a small comment, if you are using a ResourceCursorAdapter, you don't have to override the newView method. It does exactly what you are doing in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Where are your TextViews located? Or perhaps better: can you show us your whole layout file?

Both OnClickListeners are passed a View reference, but as you can read in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) the argument is the view that was clicked - in other words: it'll be a reference to the Buttons. The buttons will definitely *not* contain the textviews you're looking for, hence

`TextView tvText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);`

will result in nothing being found and `tvText1` to be `null`. That's where your nullpointer is coming from and why your app crashes.

// Edit: some code to illustrate what's mentioned in the comments below.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {        
    ....

    btnButtonON.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tvText1.setText("Off");
        }
    );
    btnButtonOFF.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tvText1.setText("Off");
        }
    );
}
```

By the way, if you're looking for a button that keeps track of it's state, have a look at [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html), which can be set to 'on' and 'off'

Comment: I posted is above as big "Comment"

Comment: I would've suggested taking the same approach Anirudh just posted.

Comment: [Please read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick). If you declare your OnClickListener in xml like `android:onClick="btnButtonONclicked"`, then you have to create a public method with the same name in your context (meaning the Activity that instantiates `ModuleCursorAdapter`). You're creating it in the adapter, which for aforementioned reason will not work. Alternatively you can just create an OnClickListener for the ON-button similar to that of the off button. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try  the following

```
TextView tvText1 = (TextView)view.getParent().findViewById(..)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It is not working for me. The error is: "The method findViewById(int) is undefinded for the type ViewPartent."

Comment: @Rajdeep, Instead of having two answers, please edit the current answer to accommodate the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Make tvText1 as the class level field for Button onClick Listener

```
class MyListener extends OnClickListener{
    private TextView tvText1;
    public MyListener(TextView tv) {
        this.tvText1 = tv;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        tvText1.setText("OFF");

    }

}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) {        
    TextView tvText1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView tvText2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    TextView tvText3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text3);
    TextView tvText4 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text4);
    ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    Button btnButtonON = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonON);
    Button btnButtonOFF = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonOFF);

    tvText1.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
    tvText2.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICETYPE)));
    tvText3.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_HOMECODE)));
    tvText4.setText(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_DEVICECODE)));

    .....

    btnButtonON.setTag(id);

    btnButtonOFF.setTag(id);
    MyListener listener = new MyListener(tvText1);

    btnButtonOFF.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Hello Rajdeep Dua. I don't know what is wrong, bur eclipse tells me: "The type View.OnClickListener can not be the superclass of MyListener; a superclass must be a class." I get this error when MyListener is inside "ModuleCursorAdapter" and also when it is in a own file.

Answer (score 0):

Hold a reference to the parent which you can use later.

so..

```
public class ModuleCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter 
 implements OnClickListener {

View mView = null;

public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cur) { 

   mView = view;
   ...
}
```

and then

```
 public void btnButtonONclicked(View view) {
     TextView tvText1 = mView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tvText1.setText("On");
 }
```

Comment: Hello Anirudh. I got the message. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to TextView." Because of this, I wrote: "TextView tvText1 = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.text1);". I made this also for the other button. For the "ON" button I get still the IllegalStateExeption. For the "OFF" button is now no exeption thrown, but nothing happens, when I click on this button. Any other idea?

Comment: Hello. I tried it another but similar way. I added a global "mContext" and a global "mCursor". Then I created a Toast in the btnButtonOFFclicked method: "Toast.makeText(mContext,mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();". It is working, but always the last entry of the database is displayed. Indipendently of the row where I clicked the button.